# ORDER BY with default INTEGER value 0

Tags: php, laravel, integer, sql-order-by, laravel-4.2

I have one field with datatype INTEGER.

I want to display products order by asc.

1,2,3,4

controller.php

```
$products       = $this->product->getUntrashed('main_category', ucfirst($label), $limit, 'top', 'asc', $min, $max, $designers, $categories, $colors, $availability);

public function getUntrashed($column, $value, $limit = 9, $order, $sort, $min, $max, $designers, $categories, $colors, $availability)
{
return Product::where($column, $value)->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('price', '>=', $min)->where('price', '<=', $max)->where('visibility', '=', 1)->where('stock_count', '!=', 0)->where('status', '!=',0)->orderBy($order, $sort)->paginate($limit);
}
```

problem is :

with default value 0 I cant make it sort properly.

help.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifically asking for a descending order. Descending is from highest to lowest.

Change 'desc' to 'asc'.

Comment: That is correct ascending order. 0 is the number that precedes 1. Do you not want 0 to show up at all?

Comment: "Of course not"? This is not a self-evident thing. You need to be much more clearer in what you're asking. I'm not going to assume things about your use case you do not specify.  Add `->where($order, '<>', 0)` to your condition chain.

Comment: ok. apologies. my exact use case is : 1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0 . i know that is not a proper ascending order, but i want to set digits for particular product and rest of the products should be listed after that.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using PHP for this but if you really want to do it at MySQL level then here is a sample

select * from test t1
order by number = 0, number;

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `number`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 0),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 0);